# Tomcat deployement error

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, jsp-tags, web.xml

I created a simple jsp application which has the following structure

```
simple

    WEB-INF
        demo.jsp
        demo1.jsp
        classes
        web.xml
    index.jsp
```

in my all three jsp file i have used expression tag to echo a string so that i can justify that my app is working fine with proper mapping.

in my web.xml i have written

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>demo1</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>demo1.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demo1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/demo1</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>demo.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/demo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

i create the war using the following command

```
C:\simple> jar -cf simple.war *.*
```

but when i deployed this war file in tomcat 7 and start the app i got the following error

```
FAIL - Application at context path /simple could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 

[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/simple]]
```

Can you please describe the above problem? Why am i getting this error? Is there something wrong with my code or structure?

Comment: Seems like the application could not be started due to an error. Have a look into the `stdout.log` file, mostly you will not an exception there.

Comment: rest of the things are correct like my structure and web.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Place your demo.jsp, demo1.jsp out of WEB-INF folder, i.e place it in folder /simple.

Comment: If i place them out of WEB-INF then what would i change in the web.xml?

Comment: then what is the use of <jsp-file> in <servlet> tag ?

Comment: i mapped them because if i got a request to sample/demo then my demo.jsp page will run.